# Регулярная проверка из сервиса

Tags: android, java

Как можно организовать регулярную проверку потраченных мобильных данных в сервисе на андроиде?

Думаю, в цикле запускать

```
Thread.sleep(1800000);
```

не хороший вариант. Что можно предложить?

**Обновление**

Я хочу проверять потраченный трафик мобильных данных, мониторить хочу через сервис и думал, может, запускать проверку трафика регулярно каждый час.
Но ведь не вариант запускать это в цикле вот так:

```
while(true){
Thread.sleep(3600000);
int mob = TrafficStats.getMobileTX;}
```

Comment: Вы то сами хоть поняли, что написали?

Comment: я хочу проверять потраченный трафик мобильных данных, мониторить хочу через сервис, и думал может запускать проверку трафика регулярно каждый час.
но ведь не вариант запускать это в цикле вот так

    while(true){
Thread.sleep(3600000);
int mob = TrafficStats.getMobileTX;}
что типа такого но с сохранением;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем сервисе объявите хэндлер

```
   WeakHandler mHandler;    
   long interval_update = 1800000;

    @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            mHandler = new WeakHandler();
        }

    Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mHandler != null) {
                        // вызов вашей функции сбора данных о трафике
                        mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask,    
                                                   interval_update);
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: А чем он будет лучше alamrManager? Я сделал через alarmManager, сейчас отлично работает.

Comment: @eldqs, я когда-то так делал. Оно работало... Но не всегда и не у всех. Хз почему, но падало. Не у меня. Сложности тут в том, что надо следить за тем, чтобы сервис всегда был запущен (что плохо), и возможны разные косяки типа постановки отложенной задачи => смерть сервиса => рестарт сервиса => новая постановка задачи. Итого либо перерывы будут или слишком часто. И оператива потребляется. АдЪ в общем. alarmManager, конечно, лучше.

Comment: @eldqs как хотите. Это предпочтение каждого, только в документации черным по белому написано - "Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler." 
(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: @nuclominus но так мне так и нужно ведь, собирать данные в сервисе, даже когда не запущено приложение или я что то не понимаю

Answer (score 3):

Вы совершенно неверно ставите вопрос. Вы думаете, что вопрос "Как регулярно запускать проверку потраченных данных из сервиса?" чем-то отличается от вопроса "Как регулярно выполнять код?"?    
Это совершенно одинаковые вопросы с точки зрения решения. А теперь подумайте, на какой вопрос вероятнее будет уже дан ответ - на более специфический или более общий? Конечно же более общий. То есть вам нужно было спросить "Как регулярно выполнять код?". А на этот вопрос ответ давался уже несколько тысяч раз, чему [гугл](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=run%20code%20periodically%20android) в подтверждение.  
Скажу больше. Для этих задач существует специальная классная штука, которая называется `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, буду знать, а нормально ли это проверять к примеру каждый час или пол часа потраченные  мобильные данные или есть какой либо другой способ проверки, если учитывать что пользователь может жестко выключать телефон или все таки это очень редко(жесткое выключение телефона) и этот момент можно не брать в расчет.

Comment: @eldqs, можно закодить получение ивентов при включении телефона, и запускать заново на выполнение свой код.    
К сожалению, некогда искать подробнее, посмотрите тут    
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android%20broadcastreceiver%20boot%20completed